What does tx method spontaneous means in arxml
I am designing test cases for an arxml database for CAN-FD bus. Some PDUs are defined with cycle time 0 and tx Method spontaneous. I am not sure what to expect here and cannot find any reference.
Can anybody help me?

Typically this means an event-driven triggering. You will probably need to ask the implementer what the event is, if it is not obvious from the PDU name (e.g. "AEB Active", "Stall detected", ...)

is it an OEM specific extension? Or why do we need a Tx method other than on-event?

It's not an extension as such - it's implementation defined

Still not fully under my belly: what is the difference between on event and spontaneous?
